# Toggle between features in a NuGet package

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I'm trying to develop a template NuGet package to be used for microservices.

One feature is that a developer can choose what features they want to already be included in the template. Ex: EFC with PostgreSQL or SQLServer, enable caching with Redis or use a diferent Serilog Sink.

This should be done via `dotnet new <nugetname> -feature1 -feature2` and so on.

I've tried to Google this issue, but most of the solutions cover the usage of the FeatureManagement package, but it doesn't seem to fit my requirements. Most of the other suggestions are UI related, but this specific project is only backend related.

Can someone maybe point me in the right direction of what I should look up?

Comment: Have you made a template.json file? https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/Available-Symbols-Generators

Comment: Yes. But I don't see how that fits into this context unless there is a way to directly manipulate what is being included in the project via the template.json file.